# Snakemake: how to best discern between the various types of Node failures in cluster-mode?

Tags: snakemake

In Snakemake, as far as I know, we can only adapt job resources dynamically based on the number of attempts a job has made. When trying to re-adjust resources after a failure, it would be useful to discern from the following type of cluster failures:

1. Program error
2. Transient node failure
3. Out of memory
4. Timeout

The last 3 cases, in particular, are exposed to the SLURM user via different job completion status codes. The snakemake interface to the status script merges all types of failures into a single "failed" status.

Is there any way to do so? Or is this a planned feature? Keeping a list of previous failure reasons, instead of just the `attempts` count would be most useful.

e.g. goal:

```
rule foo:
    resources:
        mem_gb=lambda wildcards, attempts: 100  + (20*attempts.OOM)
        time_s=lambda wildcards, attempts: 3600 + (3600*attemps.TIMEOUT)
    ...
```

The cluster I have access to has heterogeneous machines where each node is configured with various walltime and memory limits, and it would minimize scheduling times if I didn't have to conservatively bump all resources at once.

Possible workaround: I thought of keeping track of that extra info between the job status script, and the cluster submission script (e.g. keeping a history of status codes for each jobid). Is the attempt# available to the cluster submission and cluster status commands?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to handle such cluster specific functionality in a profile, e.g. in the [slurm profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm). When an error is detected, the status script could simply silently resubmit with updated resources based on what slurm reports. I don't think the Snakefile has to be cluttered with such platform details.

Comment: Thanks. That's fair. But what would be the reasoning for having the lambda functions for the resources in the Snakefile in the first place then (esp those using `attempt`)? Functions based on wildcards and rule names are tougher to move to the slurm profile.